# WEKA problems creating CSV file with attributes

Tags: weka

I wish to use this data https://data.lacity.org/Public-Safety/Crime-Data-from-2020-to-Present/2nrs-mtv8 for a WEKA project, but I have met some troubles in my way of structuring a CSV file which can be processed for insight within WEKA.

I wish to use the AREA name, Vict age, Vict descent, Vict sex, and Date Occ :)

I hope you can be helpful. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Weka's CSVLoader is a bit peculiar in the way it handles strings and quotes.

In order to load more common CSV dialects, you can install the ([unofficial](https://waikato.github.io/weka-wiki/packages/unofficial/)) [common-csv](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package) Weka package and then, after restarting Weka, you can load the above CSV using the `Common CSV files (*.csv)` file type in the Weka Explorer.

Comment: It seems confusing to me at the moment, could you guide me how I find the URL which I need to put into the packet manager tool in WEKA?

Thank you :)

Comment: When you go the [github project](https://github.com/fracpete/common-csv-weka-package), scroll down to the **Release** section (not the one on the right, which is generated by github). At the time of writing, release 2021.1.3 is the latest release. Download the zip file that is linked there onto your local machine and then install that zip file using the package manager (via the button in the "unofficial" section).

Comment: Thank you so much for your support! A new problem has occurred though, the new converter does not show up among the other converters (I have restarted WEKA). Any chance you know how this could be?

Comment: The package is written for Weka 3.9.5 or later. It won't show up if you use 3.8.x.

Comment: Thank you - I have the free version of WEKA which is version 3.8.x :)

Comment: 3.9.x is open source and free as well.